# Export/Import Settings and Preferences in Adobe Flash CS6?

Tags: export, flash-cs6

I recently got a new computer and installed Adobe Flash CS6 on it. I had changed several preferences on my copy of Adobe Flash CS6 on my old computer, and want to put them on my copy on my new computer. However, I haven't been able to find a "Export Settings" function in Flash. How can I get my settings from my old Flash to my new Flash?

EDIT: I'm running Windows 10 on both of my machines.

Comment: Edit your question and mention OS

Answer (score 0):

There are three things that I identify as "settings" that need to be transferred:
(1) User Preferences
(2) Keyboard Shortcuts
(3) Workspace layouts

Make sure that you have Flash closed first. For each of them, go to the following folder and copy over the following file:

(1) I haven't found this one yet, still looking.

(2) Go to `C:\Users\[Your Username]\AppData\Local\Adobe\Flash CS6\en_US\Configuration\Keyboard Shortcuts`
and copy the `.wfx` file with the same name as the keyboard configuration you want to copy.

(3) Go to `C:\Users\[Your Username]\AppData\Local\Adobe\Flash CS6\en_US\Configuration\Workspace`
and copy the two files with the name of the workspace layout you want to copy. One will be a `.xml` file, and the other will have no file extension

When you reopen Flash, you also have to go to `Edit->Keyboard Shortcuts` and select the keyboard configuration that you want to use from `Current Set` combobox.

That should be it. I'll update this if I figure out how to also transfer the user preferences.